# Qual è il senso della frase "Non dicano" in questo brano?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Il barone rampante*, di Italo Calvino, ho letto:

> Fu sorpresa. Molto. **Non dicano**. Certo, si riprese subito e fece la sufficiente, al suo solito modo, ma lì per lì fu molto sorpresa e le risero gli occhi e la bocca e un dente che aveva come quando era bambina.

Non capisco il senso della frase "Non dicano" in questo passaggio. Qualcuno di voi me lo saprebbe spiegare?

Comment: Il significato probabilmente è "Non dicano (il contrario)". Nessuno abbia a contestare il fatto che fu molto sorpresa. Incontestabilmente, evidentemente.

Comment: È un'espressione insolita, in effetti. Per ora mi viene in mente solo che è comune, per manifestare stupore, l'esclamazione “Non mi dire!” e questa potrebbe essere una specie di analogo nel discorso indiretto.

Comment: Per scrupolo ho controllato sui Meridiani di Calvino, in caso ci fosse un refuso, ma il testo è proprio come lo riporta Charo (vol. I, p. 709).

Comment: È un intercalare che ha secondo me il significato indicato da @abarisone.

Comment: Personalmente, da madrelingua italiano, non percepisco il senso di “non dicano il contrario”, anche perché mi suona strano che il narratore ipotizzi che qualcuno metta in dubbio quello che racconta.

Comment: Per quel che vale, sono 100% convinto che l'interpretazione di @abarisone sia corretta. È la prima cosa che mi è venuta in mente leggendo il brano.

Answer (score 1):

In italiano l'espressione "non mi dire" esprime una sorpresa, un po' come "non ci posso credere".

"Non dicano" sembra una variante, a significare "non mi si dica", "non mi dire". La forma non + pronome personale mi + infinito è spesso equivalente alla forma non + pronome personale mi + forma riflessiva del verbo al congiuntivo che può anche essere equivalentemente espressa con non + congiuntivo presente nella terza persona plurale.

Un esempio simile è "non me se ne faccia una colpa" o "non fatene una colpa" o "non farmene una colpa", sono tutte varianti verbali che hanno più o meno lo stesso significato.

Nell'esempio citato la variante suona un po' forzata, a dire il vero, ma potrebbe essere una variante regionale/temporale o una libertà dell'autore (essendo Calvino mi sembra lecita).

Comment: “Se ne faccia” è impersonale, non riflessivo.